# Connecting databases to localdb using R for loop

Tags: r, sql-server-2008, for-loop, database-connection, localdb

I'm trying to write a for loop in R that will iterate over a vector of databases and connect each one to SQL Server localdb.

```
SQLConn_localdb("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\FOLDER\\dbfile.ext")
files<-list.files("C://Users/Public/Documents/FOLDER/", pattern = ".ext")
paste0("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\FOLDER\\", files)
```

This is a simple little script that will connect the database found in `C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\FOLDER\\dbfile.ext`. SQLConn_localdb is part of a package my boss made and it is just a short hand way of getting the connection string for localdb.

There is a folder that will contain 4 database files and I'd like to write a script that will connect each of these databases to localdb in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Forgive me but in the database world there are two types: file-level databases (e.g., MS Access, SQLite) and server-level databases (e.g., SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL). You cannot really connect to SQL Server on a CPU folder file level as it exists at the server level. Are those DSN files? R can connect directly to server backends with [RODBC](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dbinterface.html).

Comment: I'm pretty ignorant about databases but I do know that these will connect because I've done it before. The file extension I'm pretty sure is unique to our software. The first line of code connects the database at that path to localdb. The second line creates a list of files and paste creates a vector I believe? (I'm still a noob on those two functions). The script isn't in order but just examples of some functions I know need to be incorporated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the below for/loop.

```
files<-list.files("C:/Users/Public/Documents/FOLDER/", pattern = ".ext")

for (i in 1:length(files)){
    SQLConn_localdb(paste0("C:/Users/Public/Documents/FOLDER/",files[i]))
}
```

If I understand, you want to use R just as programming language to connect external databases to localdb NOT to connect R itself to any of these databases.